# How do I use git with google code on ubuntu?

Tags: repository, git, source-code, google, version-control

I'm a beginner with git and google code, and I'm not sure how to set it up so that I can put my source on google code. I read some tutorials but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/hosting/settings

Click on the above link and copy and paste the line they suggest for you into a new file called `.netrc`. Then where it says code.google.com change it to project.googlecode.com where for example my project is called rentap so I put rentap.googlecode.com in place of code.google.com.

Then open a terminal and type

`git remote add googlecode https://rentap.googlecode.com/git`

except replace rentap with the name of your project instead of mine.

I personally don't know much about it, but what works for me is to use `gitg` that I installed from Ubuntu Software Center (which will also install git for you) and open the folder my project is in on my computer, click the 2nd tab and double click everything on the left, type in a summary of the changes, and click commit.

Then I open a terminal and type

`git push googlecode`

It works. When I click on the source tab of my project on code.google.com, everythings there.

As for the wiki, I don't bother with that on my computer. I just update it in my project on code.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you have git installed, from the command line you can use `git clone https://code.google.com/p/your-project-name` to copy down the files.  This will create a directory with your project name in the directory you are currently in.

You can also use `git commit` to commit changes, and `git push` to push changes up to the server.  use `git` alone for a list of all available options.

In ubuntu there is also a git GUI that you can get from the app manager.  search for git and you should find it.  it is identical to the git GUI on windows.